# How can I convert a string response to a valid JSON?

Tags: python, json

Hi I am trying to convert a string response to a valid json list of objects in python.

```
value= "{ActionSuccess=True; AdditionalActionsBitMask=0},{ActionSuccess=True; AdditionalActionsBitMask=0}"
```

I tried `json.loads` but I got the error
`json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)`

I tried to convert using regex but it only return the first object.

```
regex = re.compile(r"\b(\w+)=([^=]*)(?=\s\w+=\s*|$)")
diction = dict(regex.findall(value))
```

The result is `{'ActionSuccess': 'True;', 'AdditionalActionsBitMask': '0}'}`

Answer (score 0):

I would turn your string into valid JSON following way:

```
import json
import re
value= "{ActionSuccess=True; AdditionalActionsBitMask=0},{ActionSuccess=True; AdditionalActionsBitMask=0}"
valuejson = '[' + re.sub(r'\b','"',value).replace(';',',').replace('=',':') + ']'
data = json.loads(valuejson)
print(data)
```

output

```
[{'ActionSuccess': 'True', 'AdditionalActionsBitMask': '0'}, {'ActionSuccess': 'True', 'AdditionalActionsBitMask': '0'}]
```

I place `"` where word boundary are (note that `\b` is zero-length so nothing will be removed) then change `;` to `,` and `=` to `:`, finally encose whole string into `[` and `]` to get `list` of `dict`s. Beware that this solution is made specifically to your shown example, so please test it carefully for your other use cases.

If you have access to documentation of what is giving you said response please consult it regarding what format is used in response. If it is not proprietary one you might be able to find converter for it on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/).

Comment: Hi @Daweo. This solves the problem. The only problem if you have a attribute like IP address for example, because it contains a dot or if you have ("-","/"). "AMProductVersion":"4"."18"."2110" or "RemediationTime":"08"/"12"/"2021". It will raise json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 81 (char 80).

Answer (score 0):

Because you input the wrong JSON string, **{'ActionSuccess': 'True', 'AdditionalActionsBitMask': '0'}** and **{'ActionSuccess': 'True', 'AdditionalActionsBitMask': '0'}** should have key for them,
try this:

```
import json
data = '{\"block1\":{\"ActionSuccess\":\"True\", \"AdditionalActionsBitMask\":\"0\"},\"block2\":{\"ActionSuccess\":\"True\", \"AdditionalActionsBitMask\":\"0\"}}'
print(json.loads(data))
```

output:

```
{'block1': {'ActionSuccess': 'True', 'AdditionalActionsBitMask': '0'}, 'block2': {'ActionSuccess': 'True', 'AdditionalActionsBitMask': '0'}}
```